# Call exit() without argument

Tags: c, linux

In "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment", on page 199 (Sec 7.3), I read:

> If (a) any of these functions [exit, _exit, _Exit] is called without an exit status

I wrote a simple program to verify this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    exit();
}
```

But `gcc source.c` complains:

> source.c:5:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘exit’

How can it be possible? Do they mean, "called directly from assembly"?

EDIT: the paragraph says:

> All three exit functions expect a single integer argument, which we call the exit
>   status. Most UNIX System shells provide a way to examine the exit status of a process.
>   If (a) any of these functions is called without an exit status, (b) main does a return
>   without a return value, or (c) the main function is not declared to return an integer, the
>   exit status of the process is undefined.

Comment: I don't have my copy of APUE available (Assuming it's even the same edition you're looking at), but quoting more context than that sentence fragment might help get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you forget about prototypes (ANSI C invention) and simply declare exit as taking an unspecified number of parameters in the K&R style

```
void exit();/*unspecified number of parameters*/
```

then you can do

```
void exit();/*unspecified number of parameters*/
int main()
{
    exit(1);
}
```

and this is a well-formed program.

With this type of declaration, the compiler won't stop you from completely omitting the argument:

```
void exit();
int main()
{
    exit();
}
```

but this is technically undefined C.

In practice, `exit` is in a separate translation unit (the standard library) so the compiler has no way of messing it up, and whether the above will crash or return some garbage value depends on what your machine does if code attempts to read a register or a memory location with unspecified contents.
(The unspecified contents `exit` will attempt to grab could be a "trap representation" and then you get a crash, otherwise it'll simply grab and use some garbage integer value.)

Comment: `void exit();` this is the way of fooling a compiler. Telling to compiler that take my declaration but not the definition.

Comment: "With this type of declaration, the compiler won't stop you from completely omitting the argument:" is not actually true, as it is undefined behaviour the compiler can stop you.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use assembly it is not possible to call a function with an argument if it expects one.

1. If the argument is expected in a CPU register: There is always a value in each register. It might be unknown, but in most cases it can be determined by the control flow before the call.
2. If the argument is expected on the stack: There are always values in the memory the stack pointer points at. Same as above.

   There is only one case I can think of that is different. If the memory region for the stack is protected by a memory management unit and `exit()` can't access the argument because it is beyond the region's limit.

So you always have an exit status; but you might not know its value.

**EDIT**

If some system has an architecture as @EricPostpischil describes `exit()` will detect the missing exit status. Not knowing such a system I can only guess what happens then. It might be that the called `exit()` will return '0' (zero) to the calling process, it might as well choose another defined value, or it might take some random value.

In most cases, the result is the same: **The exit status is not defined.** But there is one because the calling process receives one.

Comment: Unix has been ported to many architectures, and some pass arguments in different ways, such as including an argument count with the call, which would make it possible to pass zero arguments.

Answer (score 1):

So I think what your book is trying to say is, "If your program exits without a defined exit status, the exit status is undefined".  (Which when I say it like that sounds so obvious it's kind of ridiculous, but there we are.)

So then the question is, "How can a program exit without a defined exit status?"

One way is to fall off the end of `main()` without returning a value.  (Once upon a time that gave you, in effect, a random exit status, although these days C is defined with a special exception, namely that if you forget to return a value from `main`, the compiler quietly inserts `return 0;` for you.)

And then another way to exit without a defined exit status would be to call `exit` without supplying a value -- that is, to call `exit()`.  Here, again, things have changed since (it seems) that book was written.  Once upon a time, C didn't have function prototypes, and compilers therefore didn't complain if you called a function without a prototype for it in scope.

But even today, if you write

```
/* deliberately no proper #include line here */

int main()
{
    exit();
}
```

you might be able to get an at least somewhat surprising, not-necessarily-0 exit status.  If that's not random enough for you, you could try to increase the odds by changing it to

```
int main()
{
    puts("Hello, world!");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I cannot compile them: ```source.c:3:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     exit();
     ^~~~
source.c:3:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
source.c:3:5: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘exit’
source.c:3:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘exit’
```

Comment: @bicup To be honest, I can't either, and for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

The edit contains 3 claims:

> All three exit functions expect a single integer argument, which we call the exit status. Most UNIX System shells provide a way to examine the exit status of a process. If
>
> **a)** any of these functions is called without an exit status,
>
> **b)** main does a return without a return value,
>
> **c)** the main function is not declared to return an integer
>
> the exit status of the process is undefined.

**None** of these 3 cases is not as straightforward. Let's tackle them in order.

First **a)**. You can call `exit()` without arguments in C89, if you didn't include `<stdlib.h>`. Then `exit` will be implicitly assumed to be of type `int exit()`, with undeclared arguments. This will lead to undefined behaviour and anything can happen. In C99+ there is no implicit function declaration so you must explicitly declare `exit` with wrong type to be able to call it without an argument. If `<stdlib.h>` has been included, it is a constraint violation to call `exit()` without an argument, and the compiler must diagnose this. The program is an invalid program. Compiler can however successfully compile an invalid program too. In that case the behaviour is undefined.

**b)** if main does use `return` without a value, it is a constraint violation, for a function that returns `int` must `return` a value of type `int`. In that case the compiler must diagnose it as such and may refuse to compile the program. It can however successfully compile this invalid program, as in case **a)**. However if the implementation uses C99+ **and** the `return` statement is omitted **and** the execution proceeds to the last `}` of `main` it is as if `main` ended with **`return 0;`**, i.e. the behaviour is well-defined.

**c)** if the `main` function is not declared to return an `int` (not just any integer), then `main` must use some other implementation-defined prototype, and in that case the implementation should probably define the behaviour. If the prototype is not of any implementation-defined type, the behaviour is **undefined**.

Now, the question is what is the limit of the undefined behaviour in these cases? It is not necessarily bounded - in fact anything is allowed, including the program *crashing* as if by signal, or the compiler *refusing* to compile the program, or the program to *hang* upon call to `exit` and not return at all. Of course it is a quality-of-implementation issue, and most compilers will probably to refuse to compile the program and *if* a program is successfully compiled, then the resulting executable would indeed return an undefined exit status.